# Detect when an outgoing call is actually answered while calling someone using our android phone

Tags: android, telephony

i know different versions of this question has been already asked, but i was unable to find any answer that actually works.

While i am calling someone using android phone, is there any way to know the correct instance when he answers my call. I need to detect the exact point when the ringing stops and the call is answered.

Comment: In simple words, you can't do this on Android as of now...